# What really happened on Kellog's boat?

Tags: continuum

At the beginning of S1E10 of Continuum, Kiera wakes up on Kellog's bed in a daze and eventually moves towards the kitchen where he is cooking breakfast. After an exchange of friendly greetings and Matt mentioning that he didn't want to awaken her (implying he was sleeping close enough to do so), Kiera exclaims "this never happened". Are we to believe that a member of CPS and one of her sworn enemies from Liber8 had sexual intercourse, simply for the purpose of stealing a piece of the time traveling device? If this is true, does this also mean that prostitution laws are more lax in the future?

Comment: Um its a strange plot point, but she probably slept with him for a variety of reasons.  Probably mainly to retrieve the artifact, but partly because she was feeling lonely and stranded, the show doesn't really explain which motivation guided her more.  It's not crazy to think that someone who is in exile might sleep with someone they don't particularly like simply for the possibility of escape.  Someone from almost any time period might consider such an option.

Answer (score 8):

**It is implied that they had sex. The fact she emphasizes that "this never happened" almost ensures she wants no conversation about it and this was a "one-time deal".**

As far as their respective factions, it is possible she considered this a temporary truce between their two groups and instead considered him as one person far from home commiserating with another, both trapped in a circumstance beyond their control.

- Her reasons could include everything you surmised, the most important being reclaiming the segment of the time traveling computer remnant.
- It is central to the character of Kiera that she is lonely in our time. She is very much a work-oriented and family-oriented individual. She is a person stranded far from home (temporally) so without a time machine, she will NEVER, see her home again. This is a kind of stranded, no human had ever had the opportunity to experience, since in her time, travel appears to be easily done if you have sufficient resources.
- It is clear that Kellogg and Keira have some sexual tension (the show has teased at it from the very beginning) but I believe it is more that Kellogg's motivations appear to be very different from the rest of LIBER8 and as such he appears to be far less of a threat than the other militia members. Sexual tension does not necessarily mean she LIKES him, per se, but it could mean she deems him less of a physical or emotional threat to her viewpoint of the future and her family relationship.
- From Keira's perspective Kellogg is a better candidate (at the moment) for a sex partner than Carlos, because there is no chance of making a mistake which might reveal her time-traveler status and blowing her chance to utilize the local police resources necessary to catch LIBER8.

Your question about prostitution appears to have little relevance in this case.

Answer (score -1):

Does no one get the phrase "any port in a storm?" What's the confusion here? He's as smoking hot as Cameron. They have obvious sexual chemistry on top of being thrust (see what I did there?)... into intense situations.  Getting  the time machine bit back was an afterthought and a way out of admitting she wants him.

Comment: Easy with the shipping, sailor!